# ssh id_rsa.pub not accessible

Tags: ssh, openssh

I have a problem when i try to use a key with ssh:

```
ssh  -i /ssh/id_rsa.pub root@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
Warning: Identity file /ssh/id_rsa.pub not accessible: No such file or directory.
```

Answer (score 2):

`/ssh` is not a valid file path, and if it is you don't have access to view it.

SSH Keys are usually generated and placed into `$HOME/.ssh/`.  I think you meant to run this:

```
ssh -i $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa root@x.x.x.x
```

Comment: ssh -i /home/root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub root@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
Warning: Identity file /home/root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub not accessible: No such file or directory.
The authenticity of host 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:--------------------------.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?       after yes and   i entered my password this error Permission denied, please try again.

Comment: @mrkemaltas Are you already the `root` user when you're trying to SSH, or are you trying to SSH from your own user account to root somewhere else?  What's the exact command you entered?

Comment: @user68186  yes root

Comment: @ThomasWard  I can not connect to sftp or databases because I can not connect with ssh. This command "ssh -i /home/root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub root@xxxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"  after entered my password  i see this error "Permission denied, please try again."

Comment: @user681886 I tried, but I get the same mistake. My problem with remote connection with server "ssh" is that I get "Permission Denied" (publickey, password) error.

Answer (score -1):

Does root on the remote machine have a password?  That is, did you `sudo passwd root` to give root a password on the remote machine?  If you didn't do that, you can not log in as root directly.

For an Ubuntu install, root's home is `/root`.

You should not need the -i flag unless you have multiple ssh identities in `/root/.ssh`.

Comment: Yes I did. When I entered ssh user@host. I see this error "The authenticity of host 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx)' can't be established."

Comment: That is standard if the host key has not been seen previously by the local client.  Does it ask something like:  'Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?'

Comment: Also, depending on your ssh client, you can set the `StrictHostKeyChecking` option to no on the command line, and/or send the key to a null known_hosts file. You can also set these options in your config file, either for all hosts or for a given set of IP addresses or host names.  You can do this on fly with the command: 
`ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no`.  However, I don't recommend doing this since it is a security risk.

Comment: Ok. However, if you answer Yes and enter the password, the server responds "Permission denied".  I changed the ssha_config file. I can not connect to the server with ssh even though I restarted ssh. I also open the portal number 22 from ufw .

Comment: Hm.  It sounds like a password authentication problem.  I'm sure you've tried logging in as root on the remote system, right, and it works?  I suggest trying this as a normal user, just as a sanity check, although I do appreciate that you've changed the sshd_config and restarted the service, so root should have access.  It does seem clear you are connecting to the sshd on the remote system so it's not a port problem.

Comment: Yes I did .I am connecting to server with digitalocean launch console but I can not connect sftp and database because i can not connect with ssh.

Comment: If you can connect as a normal unprivileged user, use that account to set up your ssh keys.

Comment: AFAIK an account doesn't actually need an unlocked password in order to log in with key-based SSH (`man passwd` specifically warns about this). For root login, it *does* however require a suitably permissive `PermitRootLogin` in the remote machine's `sshd_config`.